# How to configure my sql in phabricator

Tags: windows, phabricator

How to run this cmd in windows OS

```
phabricator/ $ ./bin/storage upgrade
```

I am configuring the phabricator in windows machine using following post.

https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabricator/article/configuration_guide/

other than configuring mysql everything is done.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabricator/article/installation_guide/

> To install the Phabricator server software, you will need an operating system on your normal computer which is **not Windows**. Note that the command line interface does work on Windows, and you can use Phabricator from any operating system with a web browser. However, the server software does not run on Windows. It does run on most other operating systems, so choose one of these instead: